# Create Dynamic second level drop down list using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create second level drop down list using javascript,but it will not display me second drop down list.There is a code which i have tried what is the change i have to do so code can work fine???

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

          $("#Category").change(function () {
        var correspondingID = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        $(".style-sub-1").hide();
        $("#" + correspondingID).show();

    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="ccms_form_element cfdiv_custom" id="style_container_div">
<label>Choose Category:</label>
<select size="1" id="Category" class=" validate['required']" title="" type="select" name="Category" value="-Select Your Category-">
    <optgroup label="-Select Your Category-">
        <option value="Charging">Charging</option>
        <option value="Consent">Consent</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="error-message-style"></div>
</div>

<div id="Charging" class="style-sub-1" style="display: none;" name="stylesub1" onchange="ChangeDropdowns(this.value)">
   <label>Which Sub-Category?</label>
   <select id="Charging" name="Charging">
    <option value="">-Choose A Sub-Category-</option>
    <option value="Charging">Charging</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="Consent" class="style-sub-1" style="display: none;" name="stylesub1" onchange="ChangeDropdowns(this.value)">
<label>Which Sub-Category?</label>
<select id="Consent" name="Consent">
    <option value="">-Choose A Sub-Category-</option>
    <option value="Accuracy">Accuracy</option>
    <option value="Double Confirmation">Double Confirmation</option>
    <option value="Single Confirmation">Single Confirmation</option>
 </select>
</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
<div id="error-message-style-sub-1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly you are expecting from this `http://codepen.io/abgth/pen/GgdQWo`
(For clarification only, same code)

Comment: its work on it but when i merge those and try to run in netbeans it will not work!!!!

Comment: Did you add JQuery, apparently jquery is missing in code. add `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` before `JS` code

Comment: Though it will not work....!!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$("#Category").change(function () {
    var correspondingID = $(this).find(":selected").attr('id');
    $(".style-sub-1").hide();
    $("#" + correspondingID).show();
```

Comment: instead of getting the value of the element selected, you've to get the id

Comment: it's not working.My previous code is already running on http://jsfiddle.net/32fc3qbc/ but when i merge and try to run in netbeans it will not work you can check it online...

Comment: I tried your code, I replaced the code within the change function and figured out that is not responding to the change event

Comment: check the firebug if you've an error in your js console

Comment: There is no error in js console. If i will give you html and javascript code sepretly than can u make successful running code>

Comment: I don't see the  $(document).ready(function(){  in your code, recheck

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by one of my friend @Pritesh usadadiya,
Correct code for javascript is below:

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#Category").change(function () {
            correspondingID = $(this).find(":selected").val();
            $(".style-sub-1").hide();
            $("#" + correspondingID).show();
        });
     });


</script>
```